# jRuby Glassfish v3 dispatcher error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, glassfish, jruby, glassfish-3, jrubyonrails

i have ubuntu 8.10, running glassfish v3 (not prelude).  first deployment of any jruby on a glassfish v3 SERVER (not the gem).

i have deployed the app using the 'choose folder' method, rather than the asadmin deploy method, though i have also tried that.

i get the following error message:

```
#|2010-10-18T16:48:01.643+1100|SEVERE|glassfish3.0.1|org.glassfish.scripting.jruby.JRubyContainer|_ThreadID=35;_ThreadName=Thread-1;|no such file to load -- dispatcher
from /home/architect/development/jruby/jruby-1.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
from /home/architect/development/jruby/jruby-1.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
from /home/architect/development/jruby/jruby-1.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:591:in `new_constants_in'
from /home/architect/development/jruby/jruby-1.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
from /home/architect/development/jruby/jruby-1.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
from file:/opt/glassfishv3/glassfish/modules/grizzly-jruby.jar!/rack/adapter/rails.rb:99:in `load_application'
from file:/opt/glassfishv3/glassfish/modules/grizzly-jruby.jar!/rack/adapter/rails.rb:75:in `initialize'
from file:/opt/glassfishv3/glassfish/modules/grizzly-jruby.jar!/jruby/rack/rails.rb:25:in `new'
from file:/opt/glassfishv3/glassfish/modules/grizzly-jruby.jar!/jruby/rack/rails.rb:25:in `new'
from <script>:1

/home/architect/development/jruby/jruby-1.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require': no such file to load -- dispatcher (LoadError)
from /home/architect/development/jruby/jruby-1.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
from /home/architect/development/jruby/jruby-1.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
from /home/architect/development/jruby/jruby-1.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:591:in `new_constants_in'
from /home/architect/development/jruby/jruby-1.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
from /home/architect/development/jruby/jruby-1.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
from file:/opt/glassfishv3/glassfish/modules/grizzly-jruby.jar!/rack/adapter/rails.rb:99:in `load_application'
from file:/opt/glassfishv3/glassfish/modules/grizzly-jruby.jar!/rack/adapter/rails.rb:75:in `initialize'
from file:/opt/glassfishv3/glassfish/modules/grizzly-jruby.jar!/jruby/rack/rails.rb:25:in `new'
from file:/opt/glassfishv3/glassfish/modules/grizzly-jruby.jar!/jruby/rack/rails.rb:25:in `new'
from <script>:1
...internal jruby stack elided...
from Kernel.require(/home/architect/development/jruby/jruby-1.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239)
from ActiveSupport::Dependencies::Loadable.require(/home/architect/development/jruby/jruby-1.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225)
from ActiveSupport::Dependencies::Loadable.load_dependency(/home/architect/development/jruby/jruby-1.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:591)
from ActiveSupport::Dependencies.new_constants_in(/home/architect/development/jruby/jruby-1.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225)
from ActiveSupport::Dependencies::Loadable.load_dependency(/home/architect/development/jruby/jruby-1.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239)
from ActiveSupport::Dependencies::Loadable.require(file:/opt/glassfishv3/glassfish/modules/grizzly-jruby.jar!/rack/adapter/rails.rb:99)
from Rack::Adapter::Rails.load_application(file:/opt/glassfishv3/glassfish/modules/grizzly-jruby.jar!/rack/adapter/rails.rb:75)
from Rack::Adapter::Rails.initialize(file:/opt/glassfishv3/glassfish/modules/grizzly-jruby.jar!/jruby/rack/rails.rb:25)
from (unknown).new(file:/opt/glassfishv3/glassfish/modules/grizzly-jruby.jar!/jruby/rack/rails.rb:25)
from #<Class:01x1719508>.new(<script>:1)
from (unknown).(unknown)(:1)
```

this is very bizarre.  i can't find much on it, but i know from experience that dispatcher was removed and one can no longer use ruby on rails apps with mongrel.  in this instance, with jruby in place and glassfish v3, i have no idea what is going on.  why is it even looking for dispatcher?

any tips on my config would be great.  what am i likely missing?  shouldn't glassfish be treating it as a rack application and this problem NOT be occuring.

also note, if i run the app with jruby in WEBrick, it's all good.

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the GF v3 JRuby scripting container is expecting to load "dispatcher" and thus is probably not Rails 3 ready. Given what I've heard from Oracle about scripting support inside V3, I'm not sure you'll see a fix for this soon.

A better option for deploying inside V3 would be to use Warbler to create a war file and deploy that.